# Automapper custom inline mapping

Tags: c#, api, loops, dictionary, automapper

I have two classes

```
 public class SourceClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Provider { get; set; }
}


public class DestinationClass
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Provider { get; set; }
    public Guid CustomerId {get; set;}
}
```

I've initialized my mapping by using the following code

```
CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>();
```

And then in my controller, I have :

```
Mapper.Map<List<DestinationClass>>(requests)
```

where "requests" is a List of SourceClass objects being passed in to my controller.

Now, this code works and the mapping works as configured. However, I also get passed a CustomerId and want to set it in the DestinationClass accordingly.

Is there any way to do this while the mapping is occuring, so that I don't have to write an additional loop to set CustomerId in every object in the list?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html#passing-in-key-value-to-mapper

Answer (score 4):

You can pass additional parameter by passing `key-value` to mapper (as suggested by @LucianBargaoanu). The custom value resolver and map execution can be implemented as:

```
// Configuration 
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SourceClass, DestinationClass>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.CustomerId, opt => 
      opt.MapFrom((src, dest, destMember, context) =>
      context.Items["CustomerId"]));
});

var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();

//Sample source class
var sourceClass = new SourceClass { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Provider = Guid.NewGuid() };

var destClass = mapper.Map<SourceClass, DestinationClass>(sourceClass,
              opt => opt.Items["CustomerId"] = "96b4b6e6-7937-4579-ba01-4a051bc0b93b");
```

The `CustomerId` member of `destClass` object is populated with passed GUID.

**Note:**`SourceClass` and `DestinationClass` definition are taken from OP.

Comment: It works without `Guid.Parse` or `ToString`. Just `context.Items["CustomerId"]`.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks. You are correct. I edited anser to remove redundant parsing. Since I had stored `string` I had explicitly cast to `Guid`.

Comment: @blazerix If you can pass your actual expression then I'll try to help.